# cross domain ajax call + php

Tags: php, ajax

I want to get data from the webservices through jquery ajax call(cross domain). After fetching data from webservices, i need to show it as a dataTable using php.
Can anyone help me regarding this or just give me some sampe examples.

my ajax function is as follows:

```
$.ajax({
      type: "POST",

      url:"my webservice url",

      //data: json,
      //contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      crossDomain: true,
      dataType: 'json',
      async:false,

      success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
          {
              alert("Download success");
              alert(data);
          },
          error : function(jqXHR, exception) 
          {
              alert(jqXHR.status);
          }
      });
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3506208/jquery-ajax-cross-domain

Comment: can you express better your need ? are you having trouble with cross domain ajax call or need guidance to show the results in the dataTable ?

Comment: Atfirst i want to solve my problem with cross domain ajax call.

Comment: i tried in many ways for cross domain ajax call but i am not able to get the data. It is always giving me error

Comment: @user2018163 what is the Error ? IS it JAVA SCRIPT Error ?? Please update your Question with that Error.

Comment: As sayed by @FawadGhafoor what you need is JSONP, since cross domain requests are not allowed - it's a security flaw. With JSONP you can only do GET requests sending a token and the server response with the same key.

Comment: @FawadGhafoor.... I tried doing with datatype as 'jsonp' but getting json parse error

Answer (score 1):

```
$.ajax({
   url:"yourPageName.php",
   dataType: 'jsonp', // N.B! JSONP   It is lower Case OK?
   success:function(json){
     // json (an  Array)
     alert("Success");
 },
 error:function(){
     alert("Error");
 },
```

});

For more info please visit here http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: i tried with datatype as 'jsonp'.The jqXHR.status is 200 but it is still entering the error function as it is throwing now json parse error

Answer (score 0):

Jsonp is better way to do it. But if you really do with json you can add

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
```

to your php code. This way your server will response any request and domain. You can customize
"*" to accept domain.
**But be aware this will cause security issue.**